# Contar numero de silabas con LUA

Tags: lua

Cuento con un archivo txt que contiene lo siguiente:
ca-la-ba-za
da-dos
lá-piz
co-se-cha.
***Deseo realizar una función que me cuente el numero de silabas que tiene cada palabra de ese archivo de texto.***
**¿Como hago para que me lea nuevamente la letra a del abecedario?**

Tengo las siguientes lineas de código:

```
     local ejer = io.open("archivo.txt","r")
     local mejer={}
     local i=1
     for line in ejer:lines() do 
        mejer[i] = line
        i=i+1
      end
      print(mejer[1])


    abecedario={ "a", "e", "i", "o","u","á", "é", "í", "ó","ú","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","ñ","o","p","q","r","s","t","v","w","x","y","z"}  
    silabas={}
    local misilaba=""

    local m=1
    repeat
         local x=1
         local y=1
         local j=1
         repeat
            local letra=abecedario[x]
            local encontrar = string.find(mejer[y],letra)
            if (encontrar==m)then
                 silabas[j]=letra
                 misilaba=misilaba..silabas[j]
                 print(misilaba)
           end
           x=x+1
        until x==36
       m=m+1
       until m>12
```

con estas lineas obtengo el siguiente resultado:

1. ca-la-ba-za
2. c
3. c a
4. c a l
5. c a l b
6. c a l b z

Answer (score 0):

No sé si las palabras vienen con el formato que especificas al inicio de tu post "ca-rro" en todo caso habría una forma sencilla si fuera ese el caso:

```
local palabras = {"ca-la-ba-za", "da-dos", "lá-piz", "co-se-cha"}

for _, pal in pairs(palabras) do
  print(pal..":",pal:len() - string.len(pal:gsub('[%p%c%s]', '')) + 1)
end

--[[
    Se imprime:
    ca-la-ba-za:    4       
    da-dos: 2       
    lá-piz: 2       
    co-se-cha:  3
]]
```

Básicamente lo que hace `pal:len()` es contar la cantidad de caracteres que tiene la palabra contenida en la tabla `palabras` durante el bucle `for`, mientras que la expresión `string.len(pal:gsub('[%p%c%s]', ''))` remueve los caracteres especiales "-" de la palabra y luego se cuenta sus caracteres con la función `string.len()` al final se agrega el "+1" por que se necesita un guión para indicar dos sílabas.